# Street Intersections with Mapbox Geocoding API

Tags: geocoding, mapbox

I've searched Mapbox's API and have tested a few popular places, but can't seem to get correct results for geocoded street intersections. Does Mapbox's API have the capability to geocode intersections that's not documented? Is there a definitive answer or should I assume it's not possible (yet) and investigate other options, like MapQuest or Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intersections are not supported as of March 2016.** I'll update this post if anything changes, but it doesn't sound like it's being actively developed from the response below (*"working on potentially adding it"*).

Email response from MapBox support:

> Supporting intersections is something that is not available at this time. The team is aware of it and is working on potentially adding it in the future. You can follow **[the progress here](https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/issues/349)**.

Link from email: https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/issues/349

Answer (score 3):

Mapbox's Geocoding API does not support intersections at the moment. The feature request is being tracked on GitHub.

https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/issues/349